# How to insert csv data into a mysql database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

This might have been asked again but I can not find a solution to my "No database selected" issue. Basically, I want to upload CSV contents to a the page and then insert them into MYSQL database. The code below does well till displaying the contents to a web page. I can not get the details into a database. I'm getting "No database selected" ...Anyone lead me through

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Upload page</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 background: #E3F4FC;
 font: normal 14px/30px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #2b2b2b;
}
a {
 color:#898989;
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
 color:#CC0033;
}

h1 {
 font: bold 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #CC0033;
}
h2 {
 font: bold 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #898989;
}
#container {
 background: #CCC;
 margin: 100px auto;
 width: 945px;
}
#form    {padding: 20px 150px;}
#form input     {margin-bottom: 20px;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="form">

<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "btccredentials";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}



//Upload File
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
  echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
  echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
  readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
 }

 //Import uploaded file to Database
 $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  $import = "INSERT into btcdetails(mobilenumber,amount) values('$data[0]','$data[1]'),$dbname";
      
  mysqli_query($conn,$import);
 }

 fclose($handle);

 print "Import done";

 //view upload form
}else {

 print "Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload<br />\n";

 print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='uploadcsv.php' method='post'>";

 print "File name to import:<br />\n";

 print "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";

 print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>";

}

?>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't mix and match `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is you have mixed up two of the functions . One is deprecated and the other one is fine , though i would suggest you to use PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php for safe DB Operations.

Now your problem lies in the below code .

```
new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); // Your connection 

mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error()); // Your function
```

Change it with the below code .

```
mysqli_query($conn,$import) or die(mysql_error());
```

Remember to use `mysqli` for all instances as you have used `mysqli` as your connectivity .

Comment: Is the error same ? If the DB Connectivity code didn't throw any error then i think you are missing something

Comment: It's fine now @Megan. Thank you